# How can I update the state of radio buttons to match carousel status?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use radio buttons like a pagination for my carousel, which works fine. If I change the slide using the carousel buttons instead of the radio buttons, the state of the radio buttons doesn't change, so the selected button doesn't match the selected slide. How can I fix this?

[Here is my template](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZrQjV)

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <center>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary active s1"><input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked>1</label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary s2"><input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">2</label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary s3"><input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">3</label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary s4"><input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">4</label>
    </div>
  </center>
```

JS:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".s1").click(function () {$("#carousel").carousel(0);});
    $(".s2").click(function () {$("#carousel").carousel(1);});
    $(".s3").click(function () {$("#carousel").carousel(2);});
    $(".s4").click(function () {$("#carousel").carousel(3);});
});
```

Comment: Please don't add "[Solved]" or similar to your title. Instead, please [accept the answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that helped you the most (even if it is [your own answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)), and if you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) any answers that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it as it is you can add

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var idx = $(e.relatedTarget).index() + 1;
    $('.s'+idx).button('toggle');
});
```

but

```
$(function () {
    $(".s1").click(function () {$("#carousel").carousel(0);});
    $(".s2").click(function () {$("#carousel").carousel(1);});
    $(".s3").click(function () {$("#carousel").carousel(2);});
    $(".s4").click(function () {$("#carousel").carousel(3);});
});
```

is not that good idea. I would suggest to change it and make it like [this](http://codepen.io/tmg/pen/eZrbpL?editors=1010)

Comment: Oh, thanks man!! This is exactly what I want, thanks a lot!:)

Comment: Sorry, but when I'm trying to implement Your code into my brother's HTML and JS, it's not working(( 
Can You watch through it please?) [Template](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOjGEQ)

Comment: @EgorGunko you are missing attributes check http://codepen.io/tmg/pen/mPLNwr?editors=1010#anon-login

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem)

Here is a fixed JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    var idx = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    $('[data-slide-to=' + idx + ']').button('toggle');
  });
});
```

[Here is the working Template](http://codepen.io/EgorGunko/pen/WwyQRQ)